# mkdir while true loop stops at 406 folders

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, 21.04, mkdir

Can anyone explain why my script stops making folders at 406 folders and tell me a way to get it working?

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf infinite2
while true  
do

mkdir infinite2
cd ./infinite2
mkdir infinite1
cd ./infinite1

done
```

I have spent a couple of days trying to figure this out and could not find why it's not working.

Comment: It looks like you reach the maximum path-length on 4096 characters ...

Comment: What is the underlying filesystem? Check with `mount`.

Comment: How could i get more folders.Is it even possible?

Comment: The underlying file system?Would that be /

Comment: I was trying to make at least 125000000 folders

Comment: `~$ getconf -a | grep PATH_MAX


PATH_MAX                           4096
_POSIX_PATH_MAX                    4096`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Do you really need to make a path that is 125000000 deep, or do you just want 125000000 folders? I mean, does it really need to be `d1/d2/d3/.../f125000000` in a single directory tree or would you be OK with `parentFolder/dir1`, `parentFolder/dir2` ... `parentFolder/dir125000000`? Even better, why do you need this? If you explain what you want to actually test/achieve, we might be able to give you a better approach for doing it.

Comment: As @terdon already commented, this is a typical https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem , so I vote to close this question!

Comment: I just want to make ```parentFolder/dir1, parentFolder/dir2 ... parentFolder/dir125000000```

Comment: @EliThrash then please edit and explain that because, even if it worked, that isn't what your script would have created. Sounds like you just want `mkdir parentFolder/dir{1..125000000}`, which will probably fail because you will pass the MAX_ARG value for maximum arguments in the command line, or crash your machine as it runs out of RAM trying to calculate that brace expansion,  but can work as a starting point. We just need to know what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

In your original question, you try to create a file hierarchy like this:

```
.
├── infinite2
│   ├── infinite1
...
│ (endless level deep)  ├── infinite2
```

and your script starts getting errors when your "depth" reaches the 406th "level". There is no known file system that can hold so many levels of sub-directories as the ones you want.

However, in your comments, it seems that you want a directory hierarchy like this:

```
.
├── dir000000001
├── dir000000002
...
├── dir124999999
└── dir125000000
```

Although it may be possible to create such a huge number of *single level* sub-directories under a directory using a script like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
let i=0
while (( i < 125000 )) ; do
  mkdir $(printf "dir%06d" $i){000..999}
  let i++
done
```

it would be *very very very* (did I say enough times *very*?) inefficient to create and use them. I *was* able to test this script by creating more than two million directories; but 125 million directories are way too many.

One better alternative would be to create a three-level structure, each level holding a thousand sub-directories in a hierarchy like this:

```
.
├── dir000
│   ├── 000
│   │   ├── 000
│   │   ├── 001
│   │   ├── 002
...
│   │   └── 999
│   ├── 001
│   │   ├── 000
│   │   ├── 001
...
│   │   └── 999
...
│   ├── 999
│   │   ├── 000
...
│   │   └── 999
...
├── dir124
│   ├── 000
...
│   ├── 999
│   │   ├── 000
...
        └── 999
```

The following script can be used to create these:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
let i=0
while (( i < 125000 )) ; do
  let a=i/1000
  let b=i%1000
  mkdir -p $(printf "dir%03d/%03d/\n" $a $b){000..999}
  let i++
done
```

Even in this case, it would be *very very very* difficult to use so many directories.

Another problem is that you may easily run out of [*inodes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) in your file system: You can get the infamous `No space left on device` error, while your current file system *does* have storage space, but no inode space is left to create a new file or directory. Please, check the `IFree` column in the `df -i .` command output, before running the above script.

So, again, I think this is a typical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) that would require a completely different approach.